# Aggregation pipeline to fetch nested language objects inside array of objects into a single document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have a collection of objects:

```
{
    "_id": "096439dc-6b57d5-470e-55bb-04ee6378edsg",
    "SomeEnt": [
        {
            "_id": "ce4by887-e589-4b71-e6s4-24d0c586k863",
            "userId": "some name",
            "name": {
                "de": "some name",
                "en": "some name",
                "fr": "some name",
                "es": "some name"
            }
        },
        {
            "userId": "some name 2",
            "name": {
                "en": "some name 2",
                "de": "some name 2",
                "fr": "some name 2"
            }
        }
    ],
    "type": {
        "_id": "b4951229-6m95-4ui8-ba27-8dcc69lk5217",
        "description": {
            "en": "something"
        },
        "code": "something"
    },
    "Codes": {
        "_id": "92ea1201-827b-411a-854b-7832995lkoib",
        "type": {
            "_id": "1189bd7785-a23f-49f1-be5a-d9l17hy563cd",
            "code": "something",
            "description": {
                "def": "something",
                "en": "something"
            }
        },
        "code": "Some Bookings",
    }
}
```

I want a single document where the name inside `SomeEnt` will be a string with given locale(`"en"` or `"fr"`)

```
{
    "_id": "096439dc-6b57d5-470e-55bb-04ee6378edsg",
    "SomeEnt": [
        {
            "_id": "ce4by887-e589-4b71-e6s4-24d0c586k863",
            "userId": "some name",
            "name": "some name",
                
        },
        {
            "userId": "some name 2",
            "name": "some name 2",
        }
    ],
    "type": {
        "_id": "b4951229-6m95-4ui8-ba27-8dcc69lk5217",
        "description": {
            "en": "something"
        },
        "code": "something"
    },
    "Codes": {
        "_id": "92ea1201-827b-411a-854b-7832995lkoib",
        "type": {
            "_id": "1189bd7785-a23f-49f1-be5a-d9l17hy563cd",
            "code": "something",
            "description": {
                "def": "something",
                "en": "something"
            }
        },
        "code": "Some Bookings",
    }
}
```

I tried to unwind and then replace the `name` with the locale but now I'm not understanding how to merge the unwinded documents into 1

```
[{
    $match: {
        _id: '096439dc-6b57d5-470e-55bb-04ee6378edsg'
    }
}, {
    $unwind: {
        path: "$SomeEnt"
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        type: 1,
        description: 1,
        SomeEnt: {
           _id:1,
           userId:1,
           name: "$SomeEnt.name.en"
        },
        Codes: {
            _id: 1,
            code: 1
        }
    }
}]
```

How to merge the 2 documents the unwind produced into 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *How to merge the 2 documents the unwind produced into 1*

You can use `$group` stage after `$project` stage to reconstruct `SomeEnt` array, and required fields,

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      SomeEnt: { $push: "$SomeEnt" },
      type: { $first: "$type" },
      description: { $first: "$description" },
      Codes: { $first: "$Codes" }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hmUcAjVYDSp)

---

**Second Approach:** if you don't use `$unwind`

- `$map` to iterate loop of `SomeEnt` array and return required fields

```
[
  { $match: { _id: "096439dc-6b57d5-470e-55bb-04ee6378edsg" } },
  {
    $project: {
      type: 1,
      description: 1,
      Codes: {
        _id: 1,
        code: 1
      },
      SomeEnt: {
        $map: {
          input: "$SomeEnt",
          in: {
            _id: "$$this._id",
            userId: "$$this.userId",
            name: "$$this.name.en"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nEyRQ2W2JaR)